# Find an html element by id and replace its contents with php

Tags: php, html

I have an html with submit button.
Submit sends you to php.

php code has this:

```
header("location:./setupOk.html");
$html = file_get_html('setupOk.html');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=valueOk]');
echo $ret[0]->innertext = "foo";
```

and this is some of my html setupOk.html code:

```
<form action="http://54.186.92.18/Pixel-Matrix/keys.php" method="post">
<div class="logo">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <label id="logo"</label>
        <!--<label for="name">Type:</label>-->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h1>Enter License Information</h1>
        <div id="valueOk">
            <input type="text" id="valOk" name="Key" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
            <button id="validateB" type="submit">Validate Now ></button>
    </div>

</form>
```

After executing button on first html, it goes to php and reloads my html website with setupOk but no text is innered to anywhere. Any solution?

EDIT:
my goal is to have a general html (with label and images) then from php, put text to that html and automatically load this html on user's browser

EDIT2:
MY FIRST HTML ISN'T THE SAME THAN 2ND HTML. FIRST ONE SENDS POST PETITION TO PHP THEN DEPENDING ON THE INFO SENT TO PHP, PHP WILL FILL TEXT TO THE 2ND HTML AND LOAD THIS LAST HTML ON USER'S BROWSER

Comment: is there a reason you are not using **<form>**?

Comment: I am using form, this is not my whole html, I didn't want to put too much text

Comment: I have no clue about the `file_get_html` plugin, but wont `$ret[0]->innertext` try to put something inside `input` tags? when there is only 1? Dont you want to use `->attribute('value')` (or whatever the equiv is)

Comment: So far from your shortened code - it's hard to say actually what's happening. Cause you are using a `DOM parser` - and not sure at which point you are inserting the text. Next thing is when you are using `header()` function with `Location` - high possibility is the next lines will not execute at all - cause browser will redirect to `setupOk.html`. So please clarify about your goal a bit more and we can talk.

Comment: @DevDonkey could you write an example for my code on an answer? if it works I'll mark it as true. I don't really mind about which way doing it, this was just a method I tried

Comment: I would, but I have no idea (or time to look up) how to use `file_get_html` I'm afraid.  look at @HimelNagRana's comment though, your `header` call is probably messing everything up.

Comment: @DevDonkey it doesn't have to be with file_get_html, do you know any way to modify html from php then load this html on user browser?

HimelNagRana updated question

Comment: Well @DaniRoca, I will say it will not be the right way to do it. You can't load an html with PHP - you can take the content > modify it > print it, etc. but that will be happening on server and on a PHP file. Whenever you will be loading the HTML file - it will load the original version. I am updating my idea in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding `DOMParser` and loading/redirecting to `HTML` page -- you can do it more simple way like (*it has to be a `PHP` file*):

```
<?php
    $innerText = "";

    if (!empty($_POST['Key'])) {
       $innerText = "foo";
    }

?>

<div class="logo">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <label id="logo"</label>
        <!--<label for="name">Type:</label>-->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h1>Enter License Information</h1>
        <div id="valueOk">
            <input type="text" id="valOk" name="Key" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $innerText;?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
            <button id="validateB" type="submit">Validate Now ></button>
    </div>
```

If you think this is **not** what you want - please elaborate your need a bit.

## UPDATE

**setupOk.php**

```
<form action="http://54.186.92.18/Pixel-Matrix/keys.php" method="post">
<div class="logo">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <label id="logo"</label>
        <!--<label for="name">Type:</label>-->
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h1>Enter License Information</h1>
        <div id="valueOk">
            <input type="text" id="valOk" name="Key" readonly="readonly" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
            <button id="validateB" type="submit">Validate Now ></button>
    </div>

</form>
```

**keys.php** *[where you are submitting the form]*

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$processedResult = "";
if (!empty($_POST['Key'])) {
    $processedResult = "foo";
}

$html = file_get_html('setupOk.php');
$html->find('input[id=valOk]', 0)->value = $processedResult;

echo $html;
```

I have tested it and it's working.

Comment: php isn't on the same file so, how would html know the value of the variable?

Comment: Your form should be in a PHP file not HTML. Then you just include the PHP file in the form page. It will work.

Comment: I shouldn't add my php file on html because it has secret info about my database

Comment: Yes you are right and that is why I keep telling you to not to do this in HTML and keep the form in PHP file not HTML

Comment: but how to echo this form then so user gets the html?